# Rails left join on two keys isn't returning joined fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, left-join

I have two tables events and assignments

```
events                       assignments
=====                        ============
sport_id                     sport_id
home_school_id               school_id
name                         division_id
```

And I'm trying to select the events and join the assignments like so:

```
joins = "LEFT JOIN assignments sa on events.sport_id = sa.sport_id 
         AND events.home_school_id = sa.school_id"
events = Event.find(:all, :joins => joins)
```

The problem is this doesn't return the division _id. Why not ? Is it because there isn't an association ?

Shouldn't I be able to do `events.first.division_id` ? I've tried this in mysql and it works fine.

## edit

My Event model association

```
has_many :assignments,
  :primary_key => :sport_id,
  :foreign_key => :sport_id,
  :finder_sql =>
      'SELECT sa.* ' +
      'FROM events e, assignments sa ' +
      'WHERE e.sport_id = sa.sport_id AND e.home_school_id = sa.school_id ' +
      'ORDER BY e.event_date'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `composite_primary_keys` gem:
https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys

This allows you to have multiple foreign keys. After that I just did an include (like GrantG's answer). Finally I used rails' group by function to get the data from the other table into the hash:

```
divisions_hash = events.group_by{|item| item.assignment.division_id}
```

As far as I can tell what I originally wanted to do (join in the other tables attributes inside the active record result for each record) isn't possible in Rails right now.

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
events = Event.find(:all, :include => [:assignments])
```

Then get the division inside:

```
events.first.assignment.division_id
```

This assumes you told events that is has_many :assignments

Comment: My problem is that I need this data in the query so I can have all the assignment data come back in the query and order by it. Thats why I was using a join. I won't be able to call `.assignment.division_id` (which isn't working for me anyway even after I added that association above).